# How to smooth bone-vertex weights using geodesic distance of vertices?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm currently researching a way to implement smoothing of bone-vertex weights (skin weights for joint deformations) and coming up empty on methods that use geodesic (surface) distances between vertices within a parametric distance set by the user.
So far, someone has mentioned the possible use of Dijkstra's Algorithm for getting approximate geodesic distances - but it has limitations over certain types of mesh topology.
The only paper that I found specifically on this issue (so-called "Bone-vertex weight smoothing") uses Laplacian Smoothing of weights on a skinned mesh, but it only considers the one-ring neighboring vertices to each vertex which does not satisfy my need to include vertices up to a distance (shortest geodesic distance):

```
L(Wi) = 1/m * Sum(j from 0 to m-1)(Wj - Wi)
```

where vertex `i` and `j` are considered with respect to vertex `i`, `m` is the number of neighbor vertices and `W` is the weight on the vertex.

What I am envisioning is a modified Laplacian Smoothing wherein all of the vertices found to be within the parametric distance are used but the distance needs to be a factor also.  Maybe just multiply the weight influence by the parametric distance minus the distance between the current vertex and the one being used in the sum.  Something like this, maybe:

```
Wmj = Wj * (maxDistance - Dji)

L(Wi) = 1/m * Sum(j from 0 to m-1)(Wmj - Wi)
```

so that the influence of the smoothing by `Wj` is reduced (falloff) by its vertex distance (`Dji`).  Of course, vertices at `maxDistance` will have no influence and might need to be ignored as part of `m`.

Would this work?

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

The first thought that came to my mind was projection.  Start by getting the line representing euclidean distance between your start point and end point (going through the mesh).  Then project that onto the mesh.  But I realized that won't work in certain situations.  For the benefit of others, one such situation is if the start point is one one side of a deep pit, and the target is on the opposite side, the shortest distance would be around the rim, rather than straight through.  This still may be adequate for you, depending on the types of meshes you are working with, so I can elaborate a more complete approach along these lines if this is good enough for you.

So then my thoughts were to subdivide and then use search.  I would use adaptive subdivision, i.e. split edges until all edges are less than some threshold.  From that point you can use Dijkstra's, or A* or any other number of search methods.  This gets around the problem of skinny triangles, because edges will be subdivided until they are small, so there will be no long, skinny edges.